# Bandwidth usage/throughput increased after DDoS attack

Tags: security, bandwidth, ddos

I have a server with Softlayer and before the attack my bandwidth usage/throughput was working at around 0.3Mbps, and then I had an 800Mbps DDoS/DoS attack that lasted 2 days, and ever since my bandwidth usage/throughput has been around 5Mbps to 15Mbps.

I have contacted Softlayer, and they're saying that there is no attack happening. Could the DDoS/Dos attack have caused something to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, May be there is still attack on your server. I think you will have to discuss this issues with your server admin.

Meanwhile, You can check your server process through **ps -aufx** and **top** command. And try to check your server connection through following IP. You will get IP and total number of connections with this command.

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```